# como estruturar os nodes php

Tags: php

Precisava que o nodes ficassem neste formato:

```
"name": "Baixo Alentejo",
"color": "#f0e68d\r\n"




$nodes[]='name:'.$row['name'] ."  ".'color:'.$row['color'] ;
```

Com este código, está me a dar assim:

```
"name:Baixo Alentejo   color:#f0e68d\r\n",
```

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou sua pergunta, mas não entendi o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Assim?

```
$nodes[] =  '"name": "' . $row['name'] . '", "color": "' . $row['color'] . '"'; 
//Array
//(
//    [0] => "name": "Baixo Alentejo", "color": "#f0e68d\r\n"
//)
```

Para formatar como *JSON*, use o [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php):

```
$nodes['nodes']['name'] = $row['name'];
$nodes['nodes']['color'] = $row['color'];

$nodeEncode = json_encode($nodes); 
$nodeDecode = json_decode($nodeEncode);

echo "json_encode \n";
var_dump($nodeEncode);

echo "json_decode \n";
foreach ($nodeDecode as $node){
    echo $node->name . "\n";
    echo $node->color . "\n";
}

// json_encode 
// string(53) "{"nodes":{"name":"Baixo Alentejo","color":"#f0e68d"}}"

// json_decode 
// Baixo Alentejo
// #f0e68d
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/q4imCx)

Comment: se meter assim fica assim     "\"name\": \"Alentejo Central\", \"color\": \"#bf664b\r\n\"",

Comment: quero como json o formato

Comment: fica assim "nodes": ["\"name\": \"Alentejo Central\", \"color\": \"#bf664b\r\n\"","\"name\": \"Alentejo Central \", \"color\": \"#bf664b\r\n\"", mas assim nao funciona.  eu quero assim "nodes": [{"name":"Alentejo Central","color":"#bf664b\r\n"},{"name":"Alentejo Central ","color":"#bf664b\r\n"},

Comment: echo "{";
    echo '"links": ', json_encode($links, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), " ";
    echo ',"nodes": ',json_encode($decode, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), " ";
 
 
    echo "}"; eu se fizer com o row da , mas nao posso ir buscar os campos todos

Comment: @user2964140 Tem como criar um exemplo no http://Ideone.com e colocar o link aqui?

Comment: http://ideone.com/EhK8TP

Comment: @user2964140 Veja: http://ideone.com/Az8Ry5 Será que não é assim que você quer fazer? http://ideone.com/q4imCx

Comment: o que pertendo é ter "nodes": [
    {
      
            "name": "Alentejo Central",
            "color": "#bf664b\r\n"
      
    },
    {
      
            "name": "Alentejo Central ",
            "color": "#bf664b\r\n"
      
    },

Answer (score 1):

Se você deseja gerar o JSON, você "deve" formata-lo como array, usando os indices.

Você pode usar várias formas para isso:

Forma 1:

```
$array = ['nodes' => ["name" => "Baixo Alentejo",  "color": "#f0e68d"]];

echo $json = json_encode($array);
```

Forma 2:

```
$array['nodes']["name"] = "Baixo Alentejo";
$array['nodes']["color"] = "#f0e68d";

echo $json = json_encode($array);
```

Forma 3:

```
$array['nodes'][] = ["name" => "Baixo Alentejo", "color" => "#f0e68d"];

echo $json = json_encode($array);
```

Resultado (em todos os casos):

```
{"nodes":{"name":"Baixo Alentejo","color":"#f0e68d"}}
```

A maneira mais fácil de adaptar o seu código, seria trocar o `:` para `=>` e remover isso como *string*, resultando em:

```
$nodes['nodes'][] = ['name' => $row['name'], 'color' => $row['color']];

echo json_encode($nodes);
```

Comment: uma observação pra quem for usar PHP antes do 5.4 precisa usar `array( => )` no lugar de `[ => ]`

Comment: mas estou a fazer uma query a base de dados, logo o campo color nao aparece

Comment: "nodes": [ { "name": "Alentejo Central", "color": "#bf664b\r\n" }, { "name": "Alentejo Central ", "color": "#bf664b\r\n" }, outup assim se fizer apenas row da

Comment: funcionou esta $nodes['nodes'][] = ['name' => $row['name'], 'color' => $row['color']];
 obrigado pela dica :)